# How do I use multiple waitpid() with explicit child pid's as parameters for specific process execution order

Tags: c, linux

Working with a parent process and two child processes, my goal is to implement a simple pipe which would send output of child A to the input of child B. I wanted to have this happen before executing parent code. Having two children and using waitpid() x2 in the parent section causes a hang. My intention is to use the first argument of waitpid() to specify each of the two children to wait for. Its my understanding this is a valid use of waitpid().

I created a simple example with no pipe and with only one child. The parent uses waitpid() with the child pid as its first arg. This works well and confirms that I'm using the pid arg correctly. Then, back in the original two-child code (below), I tried having -1 as the first arg in each of the waitpid() as I understand this is a more general approach. It still hangs. Then I considered that maybe since child process B waits for child process A before executing, by the time the parent executes its waitpid's child A would no longer be changing state, so I tried having only a wait on child B. It still hangs. I tried adding exit(0) to the end of each child's code block, but I'm thinking this is a bad idea because then when the parent's code block is reached, the children are zombies. So my knowledge gap is in understanding when exactly the children change state and at what points the waitpid() can register those changes and when it cannot.

System: Linux 5.1.15 & GCC 9.1.0 & bash 5.0.7(1)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){
  pid_t child_a, child_b;
  int fd_pipe[2];
  if(pipe(fd_pipe) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "pipe failed\n");
    perror(NULL);
  }  
  child_a = fork();
  if(child_a < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "child_a fork failed\n");
    perror(NULL);
  }
  else if(child_a == 0){
    //child_a
    printf("child_a pid: %d\n", getpid());
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup(fd_pipe[1]);
    close(fd_pipe[0]);
    close(fd_pipe[1]);
    printf("test");
  }
  else{
    child_b = fork();
    if(child_b < 0){
      fprintf(stderr, "child_b fork failed\n");
      perror(NULL);
    } 
    else if(child_b == 0){
      //child_b
      pid_t wait_ret = waitpid(child_a, NULL, 0);
      printf("child_b pid: %d\n", getpid());
      close(STDIN_FILENO);
      dup(fd_pipe[0]);
      close(fd_pipe[1]);
      close(fd_pipe[0]);
      char str[5];
      scanf("%s",str);
      printf("%d %s %d\n",getpid(), str, getpid());
    }
    else {
    //parent
      pid_t wait_ret = waitpid(child_a, NULL, 0);
      wait_ret = waitpid(child_b, NULL, 0);
      printf("parent pid: %d\n", getpid());
    }
  }
}
```

I expect child A to announce itself with PID, and then child B to announce itself with PID along with the piped, printed "test." And then I expect the parent to announce itself. Instead I get child A and B initial prints and then a hang.

Comment: A process can only wait for its own child, not for a sibling.

Comment: OT:  Please indent (at least) 4 spaces,  A two space indent can (and will) be unseen when using variable width fonts

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "child_b fork failed\n");
  perror(NULL);`  The call to `fprintf()` will overlay the value of `errno` set by the `fork()` function, so the correct text message will not be displayed.  Suggest replacing this code block with: `perror( "fork for child_b failed" );`

Comment: @user3629249: Google's coding standards require 2-space indentation (and a hard 80-column line length limit).  I much prefer 4, too, but laying down the law is dodgy...

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%s",str);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful  2) when calling the input format specifier: `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX character modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids a buffer overrun and the associated undefined behavior.  I.E. if( scanf("%4s",str) != 1 ) { handle error }`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  since we are using Stackoverflow.com, NOT google, I strongly suggest going for readability.  (I do agree with honoring the right margin, especially for display on a 80 column terminal and for printing.)  Please notice I 'suggested' not demanded a 4 character indent

Comment: OT:  regarding the assignment of `wait_ret` (2 places).  The compiler will complain about a variable being set but never used

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "pipe failed\n");
  perror(NULL);`  (note my earlier comment about overlaying the value in `errno`.  After such an error (infact most errors) the next executed statement(s) should be a cleanup, followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `close(STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup(fd_pipe[1]);`  suggest replacing with: `dup2( fd_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO )`  From the MAN page for `dup2()`  *dup2()
       The  dup2() system call performs the same task as dup(), but instead of
       using the lowest-numbered unused file  descriptor,  it  uses  the  file
       descriptor number specified in newfd.  If the file descriptor newfd was
       previously open, it is silently closed before being reused.*

Comment: The last code block (a parent) should close both ends of the pipe, similar to how the child processes did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running the following proposed code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
//#include <sys/types.h>
//#include <sys/stat.h>
//#include <fcntl.h>
//#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <errno.h>

int main( void )
{
    pid_t child_a;
    pid_t child_b;
    int fd_pipe[2];

    if(pipe(fd_pipe) == -1)
    {
        perror( "pipe failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }  

    child_a = fork();
    if(child_a < 0)
    {
        perror( "child_a fork failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    else if(child_a == 0)
    {
        //child_a
        printf("child_a pid: %d\n", getpid());

        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup(fd_pipe[1]);

        close(fd_pipe[0]);
        close(fd_pipe[1]);
        printf("test");
        exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
    }

    else
    {  // parent 
        child_b = fork();

        if(child_b < 0)
        {
            perror( "child_b fork failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        } 

        else if(child_b == 0)
        {
            //child_b
            printf("child_b pid: %d\n", getpid());

            close(STDIN_FILENO);
            dup(fd_pipe[0]);

            close(fd_pipe[1]);
            close(fd_pipe[0]);

            char str[5];
            if( scanf("%4s",str) != 1 )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            printf("%d %s %d\n",getpid(), str, getpid());   
        }

        else 
        {
            //parent
            waitpid(child_a, NULL, 0);
            waitpid(child_b, NULL, 0);

            close(fd_pipe[1]);
            close(fd_pipe[0]);
            printf("parent pid: %d\n", getpid());
        }
    }
}
```

resulted in the following output

```
child_b pid: 26137
child_a pid: 26136
26137 test 26137
parent pid: 26135
```

Note: do not include header files those contents are not used.